# Fundamental Excel VBA Classes & Objects

Tags: vba, excel

There is something I am not understanding and I guess it must be pretty basic.

Can someone please be so kind to explain to me the relationship between Classes and Objects enough so that I can understand what is happening below?
Both Location and Name are properties of the PivotTable Class and return strings.
Why do the first statements work but the last 4 give the error 
"Object doesn't support this action (Error 445)"?

```
?ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Count
3
?ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).Name
PivotTable12
?ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(2).Name
PivotTable3
?ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(3).Name 
PivotTable2

?ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).Location
?ActiveSheet.PivotTables(2).Location
?ActiveSheet.PivotTables(3).Location
?ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").Location

[Location Def][1]
[Immediate Window][2]
[Error][3]
```

Comment: Personally I've never been able to get the `.Location` property of PivotTables to work.  But instead you can use the `.TableRange2` property like so: `ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).TableRange2.Address` for the whole range of the pivottable, or `ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).TableRange2.Cells(1).Address` for just the top left cell.

Comment: Seriously?  All the undocumented nuances make this too painful to learn.
Thank you for your information!  Maybe some will have an explanation for understanding.

Comment: You can use `Location` to set, but even then it makes 100% no sense whatsoever. I think this `.Location` property was added and tested during happy hour and the documentation was written while they were passed out soon afterwards.

Comment: These comments and the answer below are great help.
Thank you to tigeravatar, JNevill, and ashleedawg

Also were my images no good is that why they no longer show or are available in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Some objects have properties or methods which either aren't available in every version, or in every situation.  Seemingly most tasks in VBA can be accomplished in multiple ways; this, it's important to be comfortable with looking for "alternative means of accomplishing the same thing."

In this case my next step would be to check out which properties/methods are available for my object in my scenario by `Set`ting it to a variable:

```
Dim p As PivotTable
Set p = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Stop
```

Run that code, and when execution breaks at the `Stop`, double click the variable `p` to select it, right-click it, click `Add Watch...` and click `OK`.

This will open the `Watches`. Use the ⊞ to open and explore the tree to see what's available in this context.

`Location` likely says "Application Defined error..." however perhaps you can find the location with:

```
?p.DataBodyRange.Cells.Address
```

or

```
?p.DataLabelRange.Cells.Address
```

...see what the `Watches` window shows as available within the context you're using.